# How to run a single test in Codeception?

Tags: codeception

I am working with Codeception Acceptance Tests in docker containers. 
I can run the whole project, but I can't run single tests or classes. 
Is there any configuration option or parameter to solve this?

This works (run all tests):

```
codecept -c /app/web/codeception.yml run
```

This does not work:

```
codecept -c /app/web/codeception.yml run SupplierFormCest (class name)
codecept -c /app/web/codeception.yml run Tests/SupplierFormCest  (Namespace path) 
codecept -c /app/web/codeception.yml run /app/web/tests/acceptance/SupplierFormCest (file path)
```

Error Message: Suite 'SupplierFormCest' could not be found

Comment: The file path needs to be relative `run tests/acceptance/SupplierFormCest` would execute the single cest, `run tests/acceptance/SupplierFormCest:nameOfTest` would execute a single test. A short form is `run acceptance SupplierFormCest`, as suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify the suite, **acceptance**, before the class name:

```
codecept -c /app/web/codeception.yml run acceptance SupplierFormCest
```

Comment: Copying @pixelbracket's comment from the other answer for increased visibility: to run a _specific_ test in that test class, you specify with a colon: `codecept run acceptance SupplierFormCest:testForm`